# Getting error while running below code on jupyter notebook

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook

After installing pyspark i am trying to run code as mentioned below and getting IndexError: list index out of range.

```
import findspark

findspark.init("/opt/spark")

import random

from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext(appName="EstimatePi")

def inside(p):
x, y = random.random(), random.random()
return x*x + y*y < 1
NUM_SAMPLES = 1000000

count = sc.parallelize(range(0, NUM_SAMPLES)) \
         .filter(inside).count()
print("Pi is roughly %f" % (4.0 * count / NUM_SAMPLES))
sc.stop()
```

Comment: Please help me fixing this.

Comment: past your exception where you are getting, This code is running file

Comment: @RakeshKumar- There was issue with python version. Now it is running. Thanks